# HtmlBox 2.8 JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using HtmlBox 2.8 (http://remiya.com/cms/projects/jquery-plugins/htmlbox/)

This jQuery plugin turns a TextArea of your choice to RichTextBox editor.

In FireFox 3.5.3 I can not get focus (cursor) into the textarea. If I click on "Html" button which switches to HTML view, the control gets the cursor and editing is enabled both in HTML and Text views.

Also I noticed that in FireFox using the demo page that is provided in the controls download package, the cursor is misplaced for approx. half height under the toolbar section.

I know this is a "long shot" question, but if anyone maybe struggled with this, please help.

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

First, download the new version of HtmlBox, because there are some compatibility issues resolved in the new version.

Second. Add an empty paragraph, and set a custom style sheet. Directions how to do it are given in the user manual, which is freely available for download on the  of HtmlBox web page.